# Run visual studio tests with selenium webdriver from task scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I'm new to programming, I did some interface tests and I would like to program the task scheduler to run them.

Some forums I found show how to do it using NUnit, but I'm using XUnit and I can't do it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the project folder, inside the `\bin\Debug\` folder you will find the DLLs you need (it will be Debug/Release or another specific configuration depending on how you build the project).

With the task scheduler you can run a program to build the project and then run the tests against the generated DLLs.